# Where can I find a tutorial on the writing of MAKEFILEs?

Tags: linux, makefile

I need to write some MAKEFILEs, but know nothing about them. Will someone please post some links to tutorials on how to create these wonderful files? I would like to study the basics of MAKEFILEs, from the beginning...

Answer (score 6):

http://www.google.com/search?q=makefile+tutorial

http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

http://mrbook.org/blog/tutorials/make/

http://www.opussoftware.com/tutorial/TutMakefile.htm

http://www.cs.indiana.edu/classes/c304/Makefiles.html

http://www.cs.duke.edu/~ola/courses/programming/Makefiles/Makefiles.html

http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2002/cmsc214/Tutorial/makefile.html

Answer (score 5):

I much prefer the dead-tree variants to online tutorials ([here](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596006105/)). It just seems (to me anyway) that the books are so much more polished, having been through countless edit cycles before being unleashed.

Most online tutorials seem to have been strung together by a group of drunken lemurs.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly a beginner's HowTo, but you probably want to read [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/) fairly soon after you begin to feel comfortable.