# Using make for my program

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile

I have a bunch of files in different folders:

```
/ai/client.cpp   # contains the main function

/ai/utils/geometry.h   
/ai/utils/geometry.cpp

/ai/world/world.h
/ai/world/world.cpp
/ai/world/ball.h
/ai/world/ball.cpp
/ai/world/bat.h
/ai/world/bat.cpp
```

How do I write a makefile to compile this program?  I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you made any effort to answer this question yourself? Explain and show what your best attend to answer this yourself. Otherwise Google "makefile tutorial".

Comment: don't forget that this website is for programming gurus, if you didn't already wrote your first OS a.k.a. Operating System, don't expect to find any answers for ya :)... I'm kidding of course but showing some basic effort is (everywhere) welcome.

Comment: I disagree completely. According to the FAQ, "No question is too trivial or too "newbie"", and "your question is welcome as long as it is of interest to at least one other programmer somewhere".

The entire point in this site is that people have *one* place to go to find answers to their programming questions, and that the answers they find here are reasonably up to date and of high quality. Google doesn't provide either of those. There is absolutely no need to google before asking questions here. (However, doing a search on SO is definitely recommended)

Comment: The question *could* use a little more detail about what the OP *does* know (if anything), what he has (or has not) done, how this effort is failing, and where he is stuck. *Not* because beginner questions are a problem, but because as it stands we don't really know how to answer...

Comment: That said, the OP's questions are ... interesting. I do hope that he is either an experienced programmer completely new to the Unix Way (tm) or prepared to spend a lot of time on intermediate goals before completing the grand task that he has set himself.

Comment: @jalf, well he didn't search: dups: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905478/where-can-i-find-a-tutorial-on-the-writing-of-makefiles http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965586/how-do-you-make-a-makefile  note on the second one, the highest voted answer is a posting of the first result of google.

Comment: actually i am completely new to the Unix way. I had no idea of Makefile. I did obviously google and understood it before posting a comment here. I wrote it but its still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) is a versatile tool, and there are many different subtleties to using it.  However, you can keep things simple:

```
OBJ := ai/utils/geometry.o ai/world/world.o ai/world/ball.o ai/world/bat.o

all: ai/client
.PHONY: all  # specific to GNU make, which is what Ubuntu provides

ai/client: ai/client.o $OBJ

# this rule means each .cpp file depends on its corresponding header
# and, since the .o files depend on .cpp files (a builtin make rule),
# they will be recompiled if the headers change
#
# you can also get more complex and generate dependencies automatically
# look at the -MM option for gcc, for example
%.cpp: %.h
```

Comment: There is one caveat which I can't remember if it applies in this case: if your make's default is to use CC to link (which probably means the gcc command), you might need `CC := g++` in the makefile to link against the C++ stdlib (or something similar, but this works well enough if you have no C programs compiled by this makefile).

Comment: @Roger: GNU make should use `$(CXX)` by default for compiling c++ code, and *that* should default to `g++`. *Don't* tell it to use `g++` for the c compiler!

Comment: @dmckee: Compiling, yes, but the issue is *linking*.  On my Ubuntu VM, make uses (as seen through `make -p`) CC to link all *.o files, regardless of whether they came from C or C++ source files.  Is there a configuration setting I'm missing?

Comment: @Roger: Uh....uh....I had never noticed that before. I habitually provide an explicit link rule, so it had never come up. I'm just stonkered. I think you'd better disregard the above hysterical ranting. *I* am going to have a beer.

Answer (score 0):

1. you should check out that you have installed **g++** and **build-essential**
2. [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2002/cmsc214/Tutorial/makefile.html) is some insight into the makefile black magic consorsium
3. I think that make[1](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2002/cmsc214/Tutorial/makefile.html) is directory aware so typing mydirectory/myfile.cpp should work well
4. the rest is basic g++ commands but the tutorial on 1 should be enough :)

[1](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2002/cmsc214/Tutorial/makefile.html) the program that executes makefiles

Comment: lmgtfy .com is a prohibited link because it is considered offensive.  Hiding it behind a URL shortener is twice as bad.  Don't do that.  Your updated link is much better.

Answer (score 0):

its working thank you every1 for your valuable comments 
specially for the links
on the previous post i forgot to write the client.cpp file on line 6
but my mistake was that i had included one header with a mistake in the client.cpp and it could never find it.

Answer (score -1):

First result in google: http://www.opussoftware.com/tutorial/TutMakefile.htm

Seems to be a pretty good tutorial. Should be pretty simple to understand, note that they talk about the GNU version of make, which is what is most commonly used. There is also the BSD version though if you use a BSD-based OS(such as OpenBSD, NetBSD, or FreeBSD.. anyone know about Mac OSX?)

Comment: So what you're saying is that you don't actually know the answer, but are mindlessly parroting Google and *hoping* the result you found is correct. How does that help the OP?

Comment: If by you mean I'm not going to give them a makefile all coded and ready for them to copy and paste, then yes. I've reviewed that tutorial, and it's good. I'm not going to try to summarize it because make is too complex to explain in one of these little answers. I wish for the asker to understand the code given, not to just blindly copy and paste.

Comment: While I agree with you on the rest, a real working example that he can copy and paste is a great addition to a good tutorial (and the best tutorials include working examples themselves).  Being able to modify and try out something as you read is central to how some people learn.